# Collection view thumbnail images not displaying

Tags: xcode, collectionview

The issue I am having is this:

1) Some of the preview thumbnails do not show, but displays the full picture when clicked as it's meant to when clicked. This is the main code that implements the thumbnails:

`  NSString *imageToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.JPG", indexPath.row];
    cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageToLoad];

```
return cell;`
```

So the '@"%d.JPG",' receives the files as need.

2)  Also, I've tried in the properties panel to change the spacings so the pictures are not right against the edge, seems to have no effect, any thoughts on this?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you can use placeholder image to show.

To answer your second question this `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate` method will help you..

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(PSUICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(PSUICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
 {
return 10; // This is the minimum inter item spacing, can be more
}
```

One more if you need more space to arrange your cells adjust the `edgeInsets` also.

Comment: The issue with the place holder as a I understand it, is that you have to have several image place holders to display the images, not just the one so the code automatically duplicating the amount needed. So in a little more detail,  the thumb nails are in folders of their own and the full images are in folders of their own. The images are there, the code simply isn't showing the thumb in simulator mode.

Comment: The second question is now sorted  though, thanks for that :)

Comment: @aaip:If this answer was useful to you in any sense. Please upvote for it.